# SwiftUI: How to constrain image size?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to constrain image size between min and max. But the view expands both width and height to their max values, removing the original aspect ratio.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImageConstrainSizeTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("bike")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .border(Color.yellow, width: 5)
            .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 10, maxHeight: 300, alignment: .center)
            .border(Color.red, width: 5)
    }
}

struct ImageConstrainSizeTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ImageConstrainSizeTest()
    }
}
```

In the screenshot below, I want the red box to shrink to yellow box.

[image: Bounding boxes around image and frame]

Tried using GeometryReader, but that gives the opposite effect of expanding the yellow box to red box.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - using view preferences and a bit different layout order (we give area to fit image with aspect and then by resulting image size constrain this area).

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7

[image]

```
struct ViewSizeKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGSize
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ImageConstrainSizeTest: View {
    @State private var size = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .overlay(
                Image("img")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .border(Color.yellow, width: 5)
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewSizeKey.self,
                            value: $0.size) })
            )
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizeKey.self) {
                self.size = $0
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: size.width, maxHeight: size.height)
            .border(Color.red, width: 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I did change the inner .background() to .overlay(), since .background wasn't working with .eraseToAnyView() modifier on the image.